# Objective C assigning a value to a variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables, nsdictionary

I have this line in my header file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *weatherData;
```

And I'm truing to do the following on my implementation

```
-(void)doSomething {

NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

//after adding items to data
self.weatherData = data;

}
```

then I have a function to get

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)getWeaterData {
NSLog([self.weatherData description]);
return self.weatherData;
}
```

Why does noting gets printed, above data has data in it.

### EDIT

self.weather data was getting populated by an asynchronous method. This does take a while. so when I'm using NSLog, it wasn't populated yet. that's why nothing was getting printed :D

all fixed now by adding a delegate call back

Comment: Is `doSomething` actually getting called?

Comment: because you never added some values to your Dictionary.

Comment: I don't think the problem rests in the code you've shared thus far (in either this or your other question). It's probably something else (e.g. some other method is reinitializing `weatherData`, your class is getting re-instantiated, because of asynchronous operations perhaps the sequence of tasks is not what you expect, etc.). You should give us a broader context for your retrieving, parsing, and then the using of `weatherData`. But the problem does not rest in the code of this question (or your prior question).

Comment: As an aside, when you define a property, `weatherData`, it will generate a "getter" accessor method of the same name, which you can use to retrieve the value from other classes. You do not need to write a `getWeaterData` getter method (and getters in Objective-C do not, by convention, begin with `get`).

Comment: *Something* gets printed.  Is it "(NULL)", or "{}", or something else?

Comment: You should never send a string you did not create yourself directly to `NSLog`. Instead call `NSLog(@"%@", string)`. This way you don't even need the `-description`.

Comment: What xcode version is that? Did you do `@synthesize weatherData;`? In newer xcode you don't need that anymore, simply use `_weatherData` instead of `self.weatherData`.

Comment: I think I have the latest xCode

Comment: Nothing gets printed at all

Comment: Issue was data isn't there when I assign it to the variable from the an asynchronous method :D all fixed now by adding a delegate call back

Answer (score 4):

I do not believe the problem rests with the code you've shared thus far. You might want to try adding a "watch" of the variable backing your class property (basically, tell the debugger to stop execution every time any code tries to update the value for that property).

If you want to do this, you can:

1. add a breakpoint in your code before you set your property the first time;
2. run the app in the debugger so it stops at your breakpoint;
3. add a watch on your variable by <kbd>control</kbd> clicking on the variable in the "Variables View" in the "Debug Area" in Xcode (in my case, I'd adding a watch on an `objects` property):

   [image]
4. continue execution of the program by hitting the "continue" button ([image: continue)]).

The app will then stop the app every time that property changes, so you can inspect what line of code is changing the value and examine other associated variables. If the debugger stops at some cryptic assembler code, click on the "step out" button ([image: step out]) until you see some of your own code that you recognize.

Perhaps "watching" can help you identify what is setting and/or resetting the value of the `weatherData` in your app.

Comment: Issue was data isn't there when I assign it to the variable from the an asynchronous method :D all fixed now by adding a delegate call back

Answer (score 2):

Where do you call getWeaterData. I dont see U making any call to that method. If you are thinking that accessing self.wetherData implicitly call the method it is not correct. It should -(NSMutableArray*) weatherData{ return _weatherData;}

Not getWeatherData. And the way U have implemented it will cause infinite loop I guess.

Comment: -(NSString *)getWeather { </br></br>    
    //return self.weather;
    
    NSString *info = @"";
    WeatherFetcher *weatherFetcher = [[WeatherFetcher alloc] init];
    [weatherFetcher fetchWeather:self.cityName];
    self.weatherData = [weatherFetcher weatherData];
    
}

Comment: if you are trying to give a custom accesser then the getter should be just the property name not getPropertyName. Otherwise you should declare your property @property (strong, nonatomic, getter = getWeaterData) NSMutableDictionary *weatherData;

Comment: Issue was data isn't there when I assign it to the variable from the an asynchronous method :D all fixed now by adding a delegate call back